# Predict function error in R

Tags: svm, linear-regression

I am trying to use linear regression using R. The following is my code, everything works fine except last line which gives following error:
    Error in .Primitive("%*%")(x, y) : 
    requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments

```
data<-read.table("tmp.txt",header=TRUE)
X<-data$P
Y<-data$Q
plot(data, pch=16)
model <- lm(Y ~ X , data)
# make a prediction for each X
predY <- predict(model,data)
```

Comment: There's no need to generate separate `Y` and `X`. Use `model <- lm(Q ~ P, data)` instead.

Comment: Yes, I did that too but it seems as if predict function isn't working. why is there the error: Error in .Primitive("%*%")(x, y) : requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments

Comment: @Akther Without any idea about your data, your question cannot be answered. Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example on how to do that. Otherwise your question is likely to be closed, for the reasons explained.  If `predict(model)` doesn't work, problem is your data, not `predict`.

Comment: I am adding my data

Comment: P
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20

Comment: Q
3
4
8
4
6
9
8
12
15
26
35
40
45
54
49
59
60
62
63
68

Comment: Error in is.data.frame(frame) : object 'X.test' not found